# Finding and changing Google file owners

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, comparison-operators

I want to be able to check a given folder that I've shared, for files that someone else put into the folder, and then take ownership of those files. I've tried this:

```
function changeUser() {
  
  var folderID = "<folder ID here>"
  var newUser = "<my email address>"
  
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
      if(file.getOwner() <> "DriveUser") {
        file.setOwner(newUser);
      }
  }
}
```

I'm using "DriveUser" because that's the user it says it is, when I run Logger.log(file.getOwner()); But I'm certainly not sure that's right.

When I try to run this, it tells me that there's an unexpected token '>' in the IF statement line. Hey - I'm new to this. In any case, any suggestions as to how I could make this work?

Comment: I just tried it without the IF statement - just set anything in the folder to me, as the user (using my email address). The new exception is: **Exception: Action not allowed.** So I'm still not doing _something_ right.

Comment: This would be better tagged as google-apps-script.  The google-apps-script-editor tag is meant for questions about the code editor interface, not the language itself.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are two issues with your code:

1. Javascript uses `!=` for 'not equals' rather than the `<>` used in some other languages.
2. The `DriveUser` you are seeing logged is not a string value, but rather an instance of the `User` class, [documented here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/user).  To get a meaningful identifier of the user, you need to call this class's method `.getEmail()`.  You can then compare that to your own email address.

So the updated code looks like this:

```
var folderID = "..."
var newUser = "(an email address)"
  
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
var files = folder.getFiles();
console.log(folder.getOwner())
  
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
    if(file.getOwner().getEmail() != newUser) {
      file.setOwner(newUser);
    }
}
```

But there's a third issue you'll encounter: This will only work if you are transferring ownership *from* you *to* another user (i.e. you own the files and `newUser` is not your email address).  Apps Script runs scripts on your behalf, which means it will not execute an action that you wouldn't have permission to do manually--only the owner of a file can transfer that ownership to another user. If you run the script on files you don't own, you'll get a vaguely worded error `Action not allowed`.

Comment: And welcome to the wonderful world of Apps Script, @David!

Comment: Thanks, and yes, I discovered that this is going to be a problem, even to do it manually. The goal was to use this for a sort of drop-box, where clients can put files they want to send me, into _their_ folder (within _my_ folder set), and then I can take those files and move them to where I need them. But it's not really looking like there's a way to do that, due to permissions. Is there any way to allow that?

Comment: You can move files without being the owner of them, if you have edit access to the parent folder.  See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file.html#movetodestination.  You could also create a shortcut in your own folder if you want to leave the original in the client's folder.  See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createshortcuttargetid.

Comment: But if you need to take on ownership of the file, you would need to create a script that the client runs under their own account, in order to pass the ownership to you.  This could be done by deploying the script as a web app, or attaching the script to a custom menu on a spreadsheet or document, which is shared with the client.  In either case, the client is asked to authorize the script to act on their behalf.